# Simulink to TwinCAT 3 code export

Tags: visual-studio-2015, simulink, twincat

I am trying to export Simulink to TwinCAT 3.I have followed the TwinCAT 3 Simulink-TwinCAT interface user manual and executed the same procedure as decscribed.
I am using windows 10 (x64) but while building simulink it's throwing an error,saying WinDD7 not found.[you can view the Error msg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGvEd.png)
Still i exported to TwinCAT 3 and tried to Configure but i encountered again Errors.[You can view the Error msg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NqwU.png)
Hope i have given enough information.
It would be grateful,if someone could help me.

Regards
venkat

Comment: I have installed the WINDD7 but this time i got new Error.Publish procedure failed
!!! See TctSmplMinTempCtrl_PublishLog.txt for further information.
!!! You can try to build manually using the project file TctSmplMinTempCtrl.vcxproj.

Answer (score 0):

You need Windows 7 driver kit installed to build simulink models. https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_c/63050395156307979.html&id=

The above link is for C++ but it applies the exact same way for simulink too. Also please note you need Simulink coder (toolbox).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have solved it and it's working fine.

Comment: I have a another issue related to c++.i am trying to call external C-function to TwinCAt c++.Here you can view the details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042462/calling-external-c-code-to-twincat-c . If you have any idea,could you pls help me.